# Unrecognized selector, Delegate problems

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

I am getting this error

> [ResultViewController setSearchFields:IndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc448840

I have a navigation controller stack in which I am using delegates to pass information back to a previous view in the navigation stack.. However I think I am doing something wrong when I am declaring the delegate.

My navigation stack looks like this.

```
view 0 (mainmenu)
-- view 1 (SearchViewController)
--- view 2 (ResultViewController) - where I set the delegate of the new view being loaded
---- View 3 (SubViewController) - this is where my delegates reside
```

What I am doing is popping to view1 and passing the delegate information to that view however by doing so I am getting this error... I am wondering if I have to set the delegate for view 3 in view 1 where I end up passing the information... is that correct??

If so what do I have to think about when setting the delegate? How do I call it from view 1

This is how I'm setting up my delegate in SubViewController

**subvc.h**

```
@protocol PassSubSearchData <NSObject>
@required
- (void) setSearchFields:(NSArray *)modArray IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)modIndexPath;
@end

@interface VehicleSubResultViewController : UITableViewController <NSXMLParserDelegate> {
//..
 //Delegate for passing Mod and SubMod data back to VehicleSearchViewController
    id <PassSubSearchData> delegate;
//..
//Delegate for passing Mod and SubMod data back to VehicleSearchViewController
@property (strong) id delegate;
```

**subvc.m**

```
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Access selected cells content (cell.textLabel.text)
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //Predicates restrict the values that will be returned from the query.
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K like %@",@"SUB",cell.textLabel.text];
    filterArray = [parsedDataArrayOfDictionaries filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

    [[self delegate] setSearchFields:tempModArray IndexPath:tempModIndexPath];

    //This pops to the View 1 - SearchViewController
    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

}
```

Then In my SearchViewController this is how I am setting the delegate stuff up

**searchvc.h**

```
#import "SubViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController : UITableViewController <PassSubSearchData> {
//..
```

**searchvc.m**

```
- (void) setSearchFields:(NSArray *)modArray IndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)modIndexPath
{
    modSearchObjectString = [[modArray valueForKey:@"MOD"] objectAtIndex:0];
    modSearchIndexPath = modIndexPath; // Sets the selected IndexPath from the subview


    NSLog(@"%@", modSearchObjectString);
    NSLog(@"%@", modResultIndexPath);



    [self.tableView reloadData]; 
}
```

That pretty much sums it up.. sorry for the delay.

Comment: Could you post the code with the declaration of the method in question and the code which is calling the method?

Comment: I am a little unclear as to what you want to do. The only thing you really need is to pass data from the table view to the next view controller, like PopUp said?

Comment: If you look at the navigation stack that I have I am wanting to pass this delegate from View 3, to View 1.. but I think thats what is causing the problem because maybe I am declaring the delegate in the wrong place or something? The thing being is I have another delegate in my app that passes from a subview to a main view fine.. but replicating all that code then trying to pass from a sub sub view up to the main view its causing problems...

Comment: But why are you trying to pass the delegate? You might be going about this in the wrong way. What information in the delegate are you using in view controller 1? It might be simpler just to store the critical information in `NSUserDefaults` (as NSData should the need arise) and then just unpack it in the next view controller.

Comment: yea seems I have lost my way abit. The reason I am using the  protocol and delegate combo is because I have read its apples prefered way of doing things. But for this particular problem I want to pop the view 3 and view 2 from the navigation controller and call the delegate method in View1. however it seems to be causing issues.. I have done it fine when I am passing from one view to another but cannot seem to get this double pop action working...

Comment: Thats pretty much it.. I need to set view1 as my delegate receiver.. but I am not loading that view onto the stack untill the view2.. so i don't know how I am going to achieve this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from what I can tell, storing the information into a file and then bringing it back down when it is needed might be a simpler way to achieve what you want. Something (I know, oversimplified) like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //store the cell's title into a string
    NSString* string = [[[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] textLabel] text];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:string forKey:@"someKey"];
}
```

Later you can get that string back by using:

```
NSString* titleString = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"someKey"];
```

You can proceed in this same way with the information that you need to transfer.

Another alternative is to create a property in the view controller receiving the data:

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString* string; //you need to synthesize it in the .m file too
```

then before you pop to the view controller you do:

```
//make sure you cast it
(SearchViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1].string = @"some string";
```

then once you go to that controller, that property will be set with whatever string you set it to in

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And in these ways you can pass information between view controllers. Good luck!

Comment: okay cool dude thanks for the help I'm going to give this a try and some research and see how I get on. Thanks for the reply.